# Incorrect count on manyToMany hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I've a bidirectional relationship between two entities: Item  (15 records) and maintenanceContract  (22 records)

Mapping table item_maintenanceContract linking these two entities contains 25 records

I would like to  count the records in the maintenanceContract table and I run the following query:

"SELECT count(*) FROM MaintenanceContract mc  LEFT JOIN   mc.items as i "

Unfortunately I  visualize  25 instead of the desidered 22.
I cannot simply count on MaintenanceContract because join with Item is required when i perform same searches based on item attributes.

I tried alternative combinations: LEFT JOIN ,  left outer JOIN, right  JOIN... no changes in the result

What I'm missing?

My item definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item"})
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Item extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

  private Long id;
  private Set<MaintenanceContract> maintenanceContracts = new HashSet<MaintenanceContract>(0);

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "item_maintenancecontract", joinColumns = {
      @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "maintenancecontract_id",
          nullable = false, updatable = false)})

  public Set<MaintenanceContract> getMaintenanceContracts() {
    return maintenanceContracts;
  }

  public void setMaintenanceContracts(Set<MaintenanceContract> maintenanceContracts) {
    this.maintenanceContracts = maintenanceContracts;
  }

}
```

and my MaintenanceContract

```
@Entity
public class MaintenanceContract implements Serializable {

  private Long id;
  private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(0);

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "maintenanceContracts")
  public Set<Item> getItems() {
    return this.items;
  }

  public void setItems(Set<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

}
```

Comment: is that query HQL or should it be SQL?

Comment: it is hql query

Comment: @pikimota Did you get a solution for this issue?